# Should I include R1 and R2 in the drawing or not?

Tags: schematics

[image]

Is it OK to leave pin 6 and pin 7 (standby/charge) unconnected if I don't plan to use indicator LEDs? I would like to make a low power board.

Comment: You could always include them and not populate them.  Always better to have the option than not.

Answer (score 10):

The datasheet block diagram shows those pins as open-drain outputs only, so leaving them open is fine.